# Accessing parent domain from an iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, filter

I'm working on a project where I render a template to a webpage serving from a different domain. To get the name of the parent domain I'm using the JavaScript code given below and adding the parent domain to the header of ajax Submit :

```
    function ajaxSubmit(payData) {
    var loc = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer : document.location.href;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/........../pay",
        type : "POST",
        headers: { 'domain': loc },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        data : payData,
    });
}
```

Every request coming from the template I've rendered will go through a filter check. Now, my question is that Is there any disadvantage of accessing parent domain like this because each request will be validated during filter check for correctness of request.